# Unable to print menu names

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm automating Free CRM website. When I am trying to capture menu names on index page(after login), I am getting the menu names along with their sub menu names(Sub menu names are blank). I just vexed with `xpath` to find the `xpath` for only main menu. I want to print only menu names.

**URL**: https://www.freecrm.com

**Code:**

```
@Test
public void Menus() throws Exception {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com/index.html");
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("XXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-small']")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    driver.switchTo().frame("mainpanel");
    List<String> LS=new ArrayList<>();
    List<WebElement> Tabs=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='navmenu']//li//a[Starts-with(@style,'background')]"));
    for(WebElement Ele:Tabs) {
        LS.add(Ele.getText().trim());
    }
    System.out.println(LS);
    String list=LS.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    System.out.println("List length is.."+list.length());
    String[] X=list.split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<Tabs.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(X[i]);
        FileWriter Fr=new FileWriter("D://MyTxt//k.txt");
        PrintWriter Pw=new PrintWriter(Fr);
        Pw.println(X[i]);
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Highlighted Main menu bar, under those submenu items are there]

Comment: Please post the menu html.

Comment: <div id="navmenu">
<ul class="mlddm" params="0,0,1000,fade,300,h,1" style="visibility: visible; margin-top: 0px;">
<li>
<a title="Home" style="background:#1ABC9C;" href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm?action=home">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<a title="Companies" style="background:#3498DB;" href="https://www.freecrm.com/system/index.cfm?action=client">Companies</a>
<ul style="width: 107px; margin-top: 1px;">
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</td>

Comment: Can you please post in detail, which is menu and which is sub menu, also screenshot will also help. Also, try with xpath : //a[starts-with(@href,'freecrm.com')] as all the menu items have href like this

Comment: Attached screen shot

Comment: HTML you posted is looks broken... Provide complete html of menu

Comment: HTML logs ate too long to post, u want main menu html tags or sub menu html tags

Comment: Did you realize you're using double forward slashes in your file specs?

Comment: @sravani: You need to modify your xpath as //div[@id='navmenu']/ul/li/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Xpath as below inorder to get only the menu names

```
//div[@id='navmenu']/ul/li/a
```

**Code:**

```
List<String> LS=new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> Tabs=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='navmenu']/ul/li/a"));

for(WebElement Ele:Tabs) {
    LS.add(Ele.getText().trim());
}
System.out.println(LS);
```

**Output:**

```
[HOME, CALENDAR, COMPANIES, CONTACTS, DEALS, TASKS, CASES, CALL, EMAIL, TEXT/SMS, PRINT, CAMPAIGNS, DOCS, FORMS, REPORTS]
List length is..105
HOME
CALENDAR
COMPANIES
CONTACTS
DEALS
TASKS
CASES
CALL
EMAIL
TEXT/SMS
PRINT
CAMPAIGNS
DOCS
FORMS
REPORTS
```

Comment: Thank u soooo much.. :)